# Prove a function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be arbitrary functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Prove the following: $$\max\left \{ f(n), g(n) \right \} = \Theta (f(n)+g(n))$$
Please help me prove (or disprove) this function as I am unsure how to resolve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as $f,g\ge 0$: $$\max\left \{ f(n), g(n) \right \} \le f(n)+g(n)$$

and for the other inequality:
$$
f(n) \le \max\left \{ f(n), g(n) \right \}\\
g(n) \le \max\left \{ f(n), g(n) \right \}\\
\\\implies f(n) + g(n) \le 2\max\left \{ f(n), g(n) \right \}\\
$$

***Conclusion:***
$$\max\left \{ f(n), g(n) \right \} = \Theta (f(n)+g(n))$$

Comment: Why did you write $f(n) + g(n) \leq \max\{f(n), g(n)\}$? What if $f(n) = g(n) = n$, for example?

Comment: I forgot a 2 ;)

Comment: Alright, it makes sense now :)